# Error: use of moved value: `path`. How to correct this code?

Tags: rust

I get this error while compiling my code: please help me.

```
use of moved value: `path`

value used here after moverustc(E0382)
main.rs(16, 9): move occurs because `path` has type `std::result::Result`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
main.rs(18, 32): `path` moved due to this method call
main.rs(19, 29): value used here after move
```

```
fn main() -> std::io::Result<()>  {
    let paths = fs::read_dir("./").unwrap();

    let mut text = String::new();
    let mut idx = 0;
    for path in paths {
        // let path_str = path.unwrap().path().display().to_string();
        let path_str = if path.unwrap().path().is_dir()  {
                            path.unwrap().path().display().to_string() 
                        } 
                       else {
                           let mut path = path.unwrap().path().display().to_string();
                           path.push_str("[file]");
                           path
                        };
        
        let path_trimed = path_str.trim_start_matches("./");
        idx += 1;
        println!("{} -> file/folder: {}", idx + 1, path_trimed);
        text.push_str(&path_trimed);
        text.push_str("\n");
    }
    // println!("{}", text);

    // writing the string to file
    let mut file = fs::File::create("file_list.txt")?;
    file.write_all(&text.as_bytes())?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're unwrapping path many times, each unwrapping borrows the variable path, so you rust will complain when you try to unwrap a second time.
I suggest you try to unwrap it just once:

```
use std::fs;
use std::io::Write;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let paths = fs::read_dir("./").unwrap();
    let mut text = String::new();
    let mut idx = 0;
    for path in paths {
        // let path_str = path.unwrap().path().display().to_string();
        let path = path.unwrap().path();
        let path_str = if path.is_dir() {
            path.display().to_string()
        } else {
            let mut path = path.display().to_string();
            path.push_str("[file]");
            path
        };
        let path_trimed = path_str.trim_start_matches("./");
        idx += 1;
        println!("{} -> file/folder: {}", idx + 1, path_trimed);
        text.push_str(&path_trimed);
        text.push_str("\n");
    }
    // println!("{}", text);
    // writing the string to file
    let mut file = fs::File::create("file_list.txt")?;
    file.write_all(&text.as_bytes())?;
    Ok(())
}
```